# MongoTemplate - autoincrement

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to implement an auto increment column in MongoDb

I am following this article: [mongodb_autoincrement_sequence](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm)

He said there to create a java script function on the server:

```
function getNextSequenceValue {some logic reading from a Sequence}
```

then calling it when inserting the document as so:

```
>db.products.insert({
   "_id":getNextSequenceValue("productid")
   ...
```

How do i do the same using the java framework (Spring and mongoTemplate)?

 I was trying to add the call to document.put(newDocument.id,"getNextSequenceValue..."

 But it will save the actual string "getNextSequenceValue..." to the db and will not generate the ID

```
    DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(DbCollections.employee);
    document.put(newDocument.id,"getNextSequenceValue(" +DbSequences.docSeqId + ")");       
    WriteResult result = collection.save(document);
```

Comment: The **example** is in JavaScript just because that's the language of the mongodb shell. You cannot do this on the server ( well you shouldn't) . You are meant to implement that logic in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

ended up using [this](http://sysgears.com/articles/atomic-value-increment-in-mongodb-using-java-driver/)

```
 // connect to MongoDB server.
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB database = mongo.getDB("mydb");
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("testCollection");

// create a simple db object where counter value is 0
DBObject temp = new BasicDBObject("name", "someName").append("counter", 0);

// insert it into the collection
collection.insert(temp);

// create an increment query
DBObject modifier = new BasicDBObject("counter", 1);
DBObject incQuery = new BasicDBObject("$inc", modifier);

// create a search query    
DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("name", "someName");

// increment a counter value atomically
WriteResult upRes = collection.update(searchQuery, incQuery);
```